# Create a click function to set a new date on jquery datepicker?

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I have a modified jquery datepicker that displays only weekdays:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1);
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 5);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#startDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
            $('#endDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));

            selectCurrentWeek();
            $('#weekDate').submit();

        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        },


    });

    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });

});
```

I'm looking to create two buttons.  One button called "next week" that, when clicked, jumps forward one week (startDate and endDate +7 days).  The second button is called "last week" that, when clicked, jumps back one week (startDate and endDate -7 days).

So far I have:

```
$( "#PreviousWeek" ).click(function() {
  $('.week-picker').datepicker('setDate', '-7');

});

$( "#NextWeek" ).click(function() {
  $('.week-picker').datepicker('setDate', '+7');

});
```

and HTML:

```
<button class="prev-day" id="PreviousWeek">< previous week</button>
<button class="next-day" id="NextWeek">> next week</button>
```

I've researched many threads and am still having trouble getting this to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/rdhutfLd/2/)**

The problem was that just using +7 and -7 was calculating with the today as base date.

```
$("#PreviousWeek").click(function () {
    var currDate = new Date($('.week-picker').datepicker('getDate'));
    currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() - 7);
    $('.week-picker').datepicker('setDate', currDate);
    //alert("hi");
});

$("#NextWeek").click(function () {
    var currDate = new Date($('.week-picker').datepicker('getDate'));
    currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() + 7);
    $('.week-picker').datepicker('setDate', currDate);
    //alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: Close... except I would like $("#PreviousWeek").click(function () to set each variable ( $('#startDate') and $('#endDate') ) back 7 days and $("#NextWeek").click(function () to set each variable ( $('#startDate') and $('#endDate') ) forward 7 days... this is only dealing with one selected date value...